# to check if the complement of the graph is bipartite or not

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

[image]
Is the complement of the above two  graphs bipartite  and should the complement of the graph include  vertex 2 ?An answer explaining how the complement is bipartite or not is needed for both graphs ?

Comment: What do you know about bipartite graphs and cycles of odd length?

Comment: The complement of a graph $G$ always has the same vertex set as $G$. It's only the edges that change.

Comment: @MarkBennet i have read about bipartite graphs that odd cycle graphs are not bipartite .If you look at the second figure , i am confused as if it is going to be bipartite or not ?

Comment: @satya: The complement of the second graph has no cycles at all, so it certainly has no odd cycles. Alternatively, consider either of the following two partitions of the vertices: $\big\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\big\}$, and $\big\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\big\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott in complement of second graph , node 1 will be connected to node 3 and node 2 is left alone so how is it possible to make two sets U and v ?

Comment: @satya: Exactly the way that I did it in the two partitions that I suggested. Each of them works to show that the complement is bipartite. In a bipartite graph any isolated vertices can go in either part.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott   can you answer the question ,it's a request .

Comment: @satya: Done. I included a bit more than I said in the comments, since I had more space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44882/discussion-between-satya-and-brian-m-scott).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complement of the first graph is a triangle ($K_3$) plus one isolated vertex; the triangle is an odd cycle in this graph, so the graph cannot be bipartite. Alternatively, you can simply observe that no matter how you divide the four vertices into two sets, one of the sets will have to contain at least two of the vertices $1,3$, and $4$, and there is an edge between any two of these vertices.

The complement of the second graph looks like this:

```
        1----3    2
```

This is bipartite in either of two ways: we can split the vertices into the sets $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3\}$, or we can split them into the sets $\{1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$. With either of these partitions there is no edge whose ends are both in the same part, so either of them shows that the graph is bipartite. Since the only edge is between $1$ and $3$, we just have to be sure that $1$ and $3$ end up in different parts; we can put the isolated vertex $2$ in either part. (This is true in general: if a graph is bipartite, any isolated vertices can go into either part.)

Answer (score 0):

The complement of the graph $G=(V,E)$ is defined to be the graph $\overline{G} = (V, V^{\{2\}}-E)$, where $V^{\{2\}}$ denotes the set of all $2$-subsets of $V$.  Note that the vertex set of the complement graph is the same as that of the given graph, and the edge set of the complement graph contains those edges of the complete graph on $V$ which are not present in $G$.  Thus, the union of the edge set of $G$ and the edge set of $\overline{G}$ is the edge set of the complete graph.  In your second example, the complement graph also has $3$ vertices.  In the given graph, vertex $2$ is adjacent to all other vertices, and so in the complement graph vertex $2$ will not have any neighbors.